# Could not find member indexPathForCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm using a UITableView that has a textFiled in a custom cell.

On event textField EditingDidEnd:

```
@IBAction func saveValue(sender: UITextField) {

    var cell = sender.superview.superview
    var cellIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)

}
```

On string "var cellIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell" I get the error

> "could not find member indexPathForCell"

**How do I use indexPathForCell in swift?**

Comment: your problem is you are bypassing to add the types for the variables and you are not seeing the `cell` is eventually not a `UITableViewCell` type, that is a `UIView`, and the `indexPathForCell(cell: UITableViewCell?)` demands an optional `UITableViewCell` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the compiler has inferred `cell` to be of type `UIView` and `indexPathForCell()` expects an `UITableViewCell`. You can explicitly cast it to an `UITableViewCell` as below:

```
var cell = sender.superview.superview as UITableViewCell
```

However, this is not a reliable way to get a cell or its `indexPath` from one of its subviews (the `UITextField` in your case).

You should go with:

```
let pointInTable: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(sender.bounds.origin, toView: self.tableView)
let cellIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(pointInTable)
```

Comment: Thanks. The first example works good. In the way with convertPoint return nil.

Comment: Println(self.tableView) return frame=(0 0; 320 480) and pointInTable return (-117.0,-70.5).

Comment: I had made a mistake in the `convertPoint` function. The second argument should be labeled `toView` instead of `fromView`. I've edited my answer to fix it.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Also, please remember to accept/upvote this answer if you believe it solved your problem. You should also do the same for any answers you received in the past that solved your problem on previous questions. This rewards the answerer, gives you a little reputation bump and helps other members in the community identify a good answer.

Comment: I'll do it in the future. Now I am a newbie, and my reputation is not enough to vote for the answer

Comment: Sure. You can still accept it though, by clicking the outlined checkmark next to the voting arrows. It will even give you a small reputation boost.

Comment: I got an error in xCode6.1 "uitableview does not have a member named indexPathForRowAtPoint" please check.