# Getting UITableViewCell data without calling didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and each cell is associated with a file.  I'm using a custom tableview cell to display the file title and each cell has a edit UIButton that is suppose to segue to another view controller that allows a user to edit the file title.  My problem is that when I hit the edit button, I'm not sure how to send the file data associated with the cell to the next view controller since `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` isn't being called.

```
struct Files {
    var title: String?
    var username: String?
    var url: String?
    var fileId: Int?
    var userId: Int?
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.fileTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FileCell

    let file = self.tableFiles[indexPath.row]
    cell.fileLabel.text = file.title
    cell.userLabel.text = file.username

    cell.editButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(HomeController.editPressed), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}

func editPressed() {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("HomeToEdit", sender: nil)

}
```

Comment: Is this edit to delete acton? or a edit action for each cell.

Comment: no, edit is a UIButton in the custom tableview cell that segues to the edit view controller when pressed.

Comment: In this case you can modify the edit function as such.
      ```func editPressed(sender:AnyObject)```

and then find the cell for the sender and then find the indexpath. This however doesnot seem natural. For more you can visit this link  [Passing Parameters by Selector][1]  I would suggest to subclass the UITableViewCell and handle this logic inside that class. This is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change editPressed to:

```
func editPressed(sender: UIButton!) {...}
```

You'll need to add : to the selector when its added as a target

You can find out the parent cell of the button by calling `sender.superView`. Cast it to a FileCell and then you can access it's fileLabel.text if that's sufficient. If not you can find the index of the cell by calling `indexPathForCell`.

Comment: not sure what you mean by adding : to the selector as a target

Comment: I changed it to `cell.editButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(HomeController.editPressed:), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)` but that gives me the missing semicolon error.

Comment: Try this cell.editButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(HomeController.editPressed(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

Comment: Combining your solution with the solution here did the job http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24354135/could-not-find-member-indexpathforcell

Answer (score 0):

Change the edit button selector so that it takes a parameter. The parameter will be the button that you tapped. You can take the frame.origin of the button and interrogate the table view and find out which cell contains that coordinate. You can then use the index path of that cell to look up the data that you want to pass the next view controller